# Set default Zoom Window font size in Access 2016 query designer?

Tags: ms-access, default, font-size, ms-access-2016, query-designer

Does anyone know if there's a way to set the **default font size** for the Access 2016 Query ***Zoom window***?

I often use the Zoom window when editing lengthy/complex expressions.  I *can* set the zoom window font size but it only "sticks" for the current session.  Next time I start Access, it's back to Tahoma 8pt.

[image: Zoom Window Font size]

I have no issue with the "Query Design Font" (`File` → `Options` → `Object Designers` → `Query Design Font`) as it [properly] stays where I set it (Sergoe UI 11) between sessions, but the Zoom window seems to insist upon a smaller font than the query designer.

[image: Query Designer Default Font size]

Maybe I'm missing something but I couldn't find anything applicable online, nor in/around registry keys:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access`

It's a minor issue but years of frustration with it is starting to add up!  **Surely there's a setting *somewhere*** so I don't have to change it every time I use Access...  Any ideas?  Thanks!

<sub>[I'm running Access 2016 (local install Version 1711 via Office 365 ProPlus subscription) on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit.]</sub>

Comment: As far as I know, that setting is hard-coded.

Comment: But I **can** change it.  The change just won't _**stay**_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zoom box is part of `(Office installation path)\ACCWIZ\UTILITY.ACCDA`. You can open this file and see the form `ZoomForm`, but you can't edit it.

Note that the Zoom box is not restricted (or specific) to the query designer - you can use Shift+F2 wherever you can edit (or see) a value.

With help from https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=238660 and https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/739912-change-default-font-zoom-box :

Set a reference to `UTILITY.ACCDA`.
In your startup code (called from an `AutoExec` macro), call this function:

```vb
Public Function ZoomBoxSetParams()

    ' adapt to your preferences
    utility.zoom_stFontName = "Consolas"
    utility.zoom_iFontSize = 16

End Function
```

It is not necessary to overwrite the Shift+F2 action with an `AutoKeys` macro as proposed in the linked threads. You only need to set these variables, and the Zoom box will always use this font.

**Note:**

This is mainly useful for your development computer. If any of your users use a different version of Access, or the runtime version, the reference to `UTILITY.ACCDA` will break.

If you are in this situation, you will either have to remove the reference and code before distribution, or perhaps [set the reference at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760521/3820271) if `UTILITY.ACCDA` is available.

**Edit:**

An alternative Zoom box is here: http://www.accessmvp.com/TomVanStiphout/ZoomBox.htm
(I haven't tried it)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  It's too bad there's no way to run a line of code for _any_ database, existing or new (the font face is fine so all I needed was `utility.zoom_iFontSize = 16`) but this is still great.  Plus now I have to see what other cool things I change mess with from the DB's in `ACCWIZ`!

Comment: Also - I followed the instructions at your other [link](http://www.accessmvp.com/TomvanStiphout/ZoomBox.htm), but I couldn't get the form to open at all (neither "as instructed" nor double-clicking to open the form).  Thanks anyhow - and the other solution works great.