# Changing default font size of Zoom Box permanently

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Using MS Access 2010,
does anyone know how to change the default font size when using the Zoom Box on a permanent basis not having to set the font size every time you open Access?

I have found an answer here for Access 2016 but don't know how to try it for Access 2010.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094712/3820271) should work for Access 2010 just as well.

Comment: Hi Andre, yes I saw that solution but do not know how to apply it. Thanks.